# Filtering StringBuilder output - Java

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

Is there any way i can filter out lines containing a certain word that i do not want? For example an example output would be

```
E/MediaPlayer( 7616): error (1, -2147483648)
D/MediaPlayer( 7616): create failed:
D/MediaPlayer( 7616): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
D/MediaPlayer( 7616):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
D/MediaPlayer( 7616):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:632)
D/MediaPlayer( 7616):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:609)
```

However i only want the first three lines without the "at" in them to be written into the StringBuilder. Is there any way to filter out lines containing the word "at"?

```
while ((finalresult = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    log.append("Error for file: "+ location.toString() + " " + finalresult +  "\n");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String regex = " at ";
str.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

where regex is regular expression and is described more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use regular expressions? 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html

```
String s = "sth";
if(s.matches("[a-zA-Z]* at * [a-zA-Z]")){
   do_something();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check

```
if (finalresult.contains(":   at ")) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are linux user you can use grep command to filter in the console output. This is not solution for the thing you want to do it, but adb logcat | grep "something" it really helps